# How can I improve the performance of this R code?

Tags: r

I'm having trouble with the performance of this code. I have to loop through 2225 columns and calculate a betti_number. I'm wondering if there is some way to speed this up. I'd like a list of betti numbers at the end so I can add it to an excel file.

```
library(nonlinearTseries)
library(TDAstats)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(tm) #NLP

betti_num_list <- list()
for (i in 1:ncol(wordvec_df)){
vec <- zoo::na.trim(wordvec_df[,i], is.na = "all") #Removes NA's from bottom of vector
text_vector_matrix <- data.matrix(vec)
tak <- buildTakens(text_vector_matrix,2,3)
hom <- calculate_homology(tak,return_df = TRUE) 
hom <- hom %>%
  mutate(persistence = death-birth) %>%
  mutate(persistent = ifelse(persistence > 0.1, 1,0))
hom_matrix <- tibble(hom) %>% select(dimension, persistent)
betti_num <- sum(hom$persistent == 1 & hom$dimension == 1)
betti_num_list <- append(betti_num_list, betti_num)
}
```

Here's some dummy code to try it with

```
V1 <- c(1,0,0,0,0,1,2,NA)
V2 <- c(2,1,1,0,0,1,NA,NA)
V3 <- c(1,2,1,0,0,NA,NA,NA)

wordvec_df <- data.frame(V1,V2,V3)
```

There are varying numbers of NA's at the bottom of each column because they're not all the same length.

Comment: When trying to speed up performance, I recommend using the `profvis` package to first see at which point in your code the speed/memory bottlenecks are occurring to see which part of the code needs to be changed. From your example, it's not clear what `buildTakens` and `calculate_homology` are doing.

Comment: buildTakens is embedding a 1-dimensional vector into 2-dimensions but doesn't plot it. calculate_homology takes the 2-dimensional embedding (pointcloud data set)  and calculates the persistent homology of it. Its a prebuilt function from TDAstats

Comment: OK, just for future reference it's always a good idea to include all the packages that you use (or include the namespace for less-commonly known functions)! Again, I'd recommend profiling your code (see https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218221837-Profiling-with-RStudio). How long is your code currently taking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to check if the betti numbers make sense, I couldn't get your code to work 100%. For the same reason I also haven't done any benchmarks, but I expect it to give some improvement. The main issues I see with your code are a number of unnecessary steps (mainly remappings) and use of inefficient data structures (use vector, matrix and array when possible).

```
library(TDAstats)
library(nonlinearTseries)

bettinum <- function(vec, embedding.dim=2, time.lag=3) {
    hom <- calculate_homology(buildTakens(vec, embedding.dim, time.lag))
    sum((hom[, "death"] - hom[, "birth"] > 0.1) & hom[, "dimension"] == 1) 
}

set.seed(1)
vec_list <- lapply(8:20, function(x) sample(0:5, x, rep=TRUE))

betti <- sapply(vec_list, bettinum)
betti
#  [1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1
```

Comment: That's definitely an improvement, Could you explain to me how vec_list <- lapply(8:20, function(x) sample(0:5, x, rep=TRUE)) works?

Comment: @MattOReilly: It just generates some example data, picking _x_ random integers between 0 and 5, with _x_ = {8..20}.